# How should you ensure state update order in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, settimeout, event-loop

I have a couple set states on providers that trigger a bunch of effects throughout my react app. They happen back to back in a hook. The second set state has some effects that it triggers that need make sure that the first hook fully propagated through the app. Currently the first one has not made all the required changes so some functionality triggered by the second causing weird behavior. How do you ensure that the second one only happens after the first is fully propagated?

```
setSomeStateValue(x);
setValueToTriggersEffectsThatRelyOnUpdatesFromTheOther(y);
```

Here are some thing I have done that work but have their issues:

1.) settimeout(...,0)

```
setSomeStateValue(x);
setTimeout(otherSetState,0);
```

This pushes the second one to a subsequent batch. I like this one because it doesn't involve adding extra code to watch other state variables that the code maybe shouldn't be concerned with, but it does seem a little black magicy and could possibly cause hard to debug issues.

2.) monitor the stuff i need set before calling the second set state

This one seems a little more readable but involves importing and watching things that might not make sense that they belong in the related code. Basically adding a useEffect that watches everything I need set before the second call happens. Also if something changes in regards to what is needed to have the second call ready then this code will have to change as well where as the first solution should not require an update.

Both of these work but have their fallbacks. I would like to refactor the second call to account for these issues but that would be too large of a refactor at this point too make it a feasible option. Is there a native way to ensure this or another strategy here that I am missing? And if not, which one of the above solutions is better?

Comment: I've seen large and complex state in big react applications, but never ran into this problem. It sounds like it's probably due to poor design of your state and the downstream effects that state changes trigger. May this should be one state value (an object with multiple fields) instead? So how are these linked? What's an example of the effects that are problematic? If you aren't willing to refactor that stuff, then `setTimeout` is probably your best bet, but it's a hack and definitely sets a bad precedent in your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

In such situations where a setState is dependent on a previous setState or a specific state of the component, you can potentially do two things. First,

1. use the second argument of setState. Here, callback is only invoked once setState is done updating the state. Hence you can get the desired synchronous behaviour.

```
setState(updater, [callback])
```

2. Use componentDidUpdate lifecycle method ( For Hooks, it would be just another useEffect ). If you don't want to have complex setStates in your component, simply have an effect with a dependency on the needed state and do your operations there

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 if( desired_state){
    secondSetState()
 },
 [ desired_state ]
}
```